# Where can I find the collectibles for the last page of the Collectopaedia?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles

I'm about 30 hours into *Xenoblade Chronicles*, and one thing I've made a point of doing in every region is filling up the Collectopaedia with all of the various shiny blue dots of fun that are scattered around the world map.

Normally, with each subsequent area I enter, a new page is added to the Collectopaedia, starting with Colony 9, then with Tephra Cave, and on to the Bionis Leg, and so on and so forth. However, since I've started playing, there has been a page marked 'Other', with far fewer 'open slots' than any other page. I am yet to find *any* items that belong on this page. Where are they? What are my rewards for finding them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To quote [Split Infinity's Xenoblade Chronicles: Achievement/Collectopaedia List](http://www.gamefaqs.com/wii/960564-xenoblade-chronicles/faqs/62859):

> **The items in Other category can only be obtained by trading!**
>
> - Minute Mantis from Sonia in Colony 9 (4* affinity)
> - Love Beetle from Lupa in Frontier Village (3* affinity)
> - Golden Cog from Oleksiy in Colony 6 (5* affinity)
> - Angel Engine Y from Rakzet in Machina Village (5* affinity)
> - Thunder Compass from Jarack in Ether Plant, Eryth Sea (5* affinity)
> - Coin of Fortune from Mac'rish in Colony 6 (5* affinity)
> - Love Source from Jer'ell in Colony 6 (5* affinity)

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Is there some way that I can improve this answer to better answer your question?

Comment: Minute Mantis requires 3* affinity with Colony 9, not 4* (tried to suggest an edit to the answer, but edits must be over 6 characters - I only needed to change 1!)

Comment: I have no problem updating the answer if it is incorrect, but I would ask for a source. I thoroughly source my answers and the only place with any discrepancy that I found is the wikia page which lists 3* affinity for many of the 4* and 5* affinity items. Minute Mantis being 4* is repeated in multiple sources (which could be a case of echoing this answer) so I would ask for confirmation before gladly making the change. It will take me a while to play up to that point to confirm personally.

Comment: All I can offer as confirmation is the wiki source, and my own personal experience - I've been replaying it recently and the Minute Mantis was in Sonia's inventory at 3* (checked beforehand, and was too early into the adventure to reach 4* - further quests unavailable until story progress on Bionis Leg)

Comment: Unfortunately I've played further since then, so can't provide photo/video evidence - my Colony 9 affinity is now at 4* (achieved just yesterday - I'm doing a very thorough run. I saw minute mantis at least a few days ago)