# Is it worth becoming a Master Trader? Or is it just a waste of time?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles

I've occasionally traded with some townsfolk to short-circuit a quest with a poor drop rate after googling to figure out what mobs I needed to kill, but it seems like, for the most part, all any of them carry is useless junk.

Do any of the townsfolk ever carry anything useful or rare, such as Arts Manuals or better weapons/armor/gems than I've been able to acquire before meeting them?

If so, how can I tell? Is there a list anywhere? Or is trading mostly just a waste of time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Trading with NPCs will get you [other items for your Collectopeadia](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64514/where-can-i-find-the-collectibles-for-the-last-page-of-the-collectopaedia), [specific monster drops, some useful gems and a few pieces of equipment](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/960564-/62493791), making it worthwhile.**

By "overtrading" (trading something of much higher value than what they are offering), you can get their more valuable alternate trade items. There are 165 entries in [this mostly complete list](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/lv?hl=en_US&key=0Anx12MiCQejudHJfUWhOTGd5Wm1uS25ub2FDeE5BekE&hl=en_US&f=true&gid=11).

Comment: Wait... Trade List? There's some way for me to go back and check what everybody has to trade without actually finding them all? What foul sorcery is this?

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Sorry about that. I misread that gamefaqs thread while getting supper ready XP. It has been corrected. I couldn't enter the table data as it greatly exceeded 30000 characters. What kind of shorter list would you like?